# Why is sending files from Host OS to Guest OS slower than the opposite (Guest->Host)?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, ubuntu, tcp

By using sockets in Python to send a 3GB file, I saw that sending it from host to guest os is much slower (~450 seconds) than using the same script to send it from guest os to host (~13 seconds)

I did expect the VM to be slower than the host, but not that much. I used TCP sockets for both and I used the same code. It's a simple server-client socket code in which server reads a file and sends it to client. Also, both host and guest are ubuntu.

Comment: diff disk write speed?

Comment: What and how exactly did you test? Does your code really only depends on network I/O or are there other dependencies like disk I/O? Are there any configurations which might limit network throughput, like firewall rules. What is the configuration of the VM, like what type of network card is used for emulation ...

Comment: @JiangYD I guess disk write speed should be the same cause there is only one ssd in the PC.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I made a 3GB file with random content (with "head -c 3G </dev/urandom > data/big" command) and made a 'server' send it to a 'client'. I guess code depends on I/O since one side reads a file in chunks, sends those chunks to other side, clients takes them and write them to a file. I used VMWare Player for making a guest, and I used bridged connection. Any other detail about network card and throughput I don't really know, cause I'm new to this.

Comment: actually VM disk write may better performance because virtual-disk cache?